# How to Test code based on HTTP Connections

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm working on a system that parses XML retrieved from an HTTP endpoint. When I considered how to test my code, I don't want my Unit Tests actually making HTTP requests to live sites. Just seems like good practice.

So I took the code that reads the contents of the end-point and wrapped it in this class, so I can mock it out with Mockito. But now, how do I write unit tests for this class? I've just pushed the problem down, and now I still have to contend with it.

I could wrap the URL object *again*, but I'm just passing the buck.

I'm trying to follow the *3 Laws of TDD* from "Clean Code"

- **FIRST LAW:** You may not write production code until you have a written a failing unit test.
- **SECOND LAW:** You may not write more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail.
- **THIRD LAW:** You may not write more production code than is sufficient to pass the currently failing test.

I've already violated the first law by completing this class, but I don't understand how to approach this problem with unit tests. Any advice?

```
/**
 * Fetches the content from an HTTP Resource
 */
public class HttpFetcher {

    /**
     * Gets the contents of an HTTP Endpoint using Basic Auth, similar to how Postman (chrome extenstion) does.
     *
     * @param username Username to authenticate with
     * @param password Password to authenticate with
     * @param url URL of the endpoint to read.
     * @return Contents read from the endpoint as a String.
     * @throws HttpException if any errors are encountered.
     */
    public String get(String username, String password, String url) {
        URLConnection connection;

        // Establish Connection
        try {
            connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            String credentials = encodeCredentials(username, password);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new HttpException(String.format("'%s' is not a valid URL.", e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new HttpException(String.format("Failed to connect to url: '%s'", url), e);
        }

        // Read the response
        try {
            String contents = readInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            return contents;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new HttpException(String.format("Failed to read from the url: '%s' ", url), e);
        }
    }

    private String encodeCredentials(String username, String password) {
        String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", username, password);
        String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));
        return encodedCredentials;
    }

    private String readInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the creation of the Connection to some external class and then mock that class:

```
class HttpFetcher {
  private final ConnectionCreator connectionCreator;

  ...

  public HttpFetcher(ConnectionCreator connectionCreator) { this.connectionCreator = connectionCreator; }
  public String get(...) {
    ...
    try {
      connection = connectionCreator.createConnectionForUrl(url);
      ...
```

This would also be a small improvement towards the Single Responsibility Principle: One class is for fetching data from a connection and one is for actually creating a connection.

Comment: This I like. It gives me a hook to inject more mocks, and doesn't require me to include yet another mocking framework. As a bonus, I can test this new class without actually establishing a connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) for this.  This a tool you can use to spin up a local server precisely for these kinds of tests.

An example of such a test is copied below:

```
@Test
public void exampleTest() {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/my/resource"))
            .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("text/xml"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                .withBody("<response>Some content</response>")));

    Result result = myHttpServiceCallingObject.doSomething();

    assertTrue(result.wasSuccessful());

    verify(postRequestedFor(urlMatching("/my/resource/[a-z0-9]+"))
            .withRequestBody(matching(".*<message>1234</message>.*"))
            .withHeader("Content-Type", notMatching("application/json")));
}
```